# How Procedural Should jQuery Be

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I don't want to start a raging argument, but I need to know this. I am writing a jQuery script to handle dynamic page elements. I'm following a very OOP style of coding and my question is: is this a good idea or best practice with Javascript?

My script file:

```
(function($){
    hideConditionalSelects = function() {
        $('.hiddenchild').closest('tr').addClass('hidefield');
    }
    showSelectDropdown = function(theFieldName) {
        hideConditionalSelects();
        $('.toggle' + theFieldName).closest('tr').removeClass('hidefield');
    }
    toggleFieldVisibiltyByClass = function() {
        $('.toggletype').change(function(){
            var toggleElem = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
            showSelectDropdown(toggleElem);
        });
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
        hideConditionalSelects();
        toggleFieldVisibiltyByClass();
    });
})(jQuery);
```

This script will easily become 300 - 400 lines long soon and I want to know if this way of writing is a good idea with jQuery before I get too far.

Does it hinder rendering times, etc? Should I write more 'procedurally'? I hope my question is clear and I appreciate your input. Thanks!

Comment: Personally i'm not a fan of doing it in that way, but one thing you've missed is you left off the `var` keyword, meaning all of those variables are global. performance isn't a concern at this point, but maintainability is.

Comment: @KevinB Maybe he wants the functions global so they can be reused.

Comment: Yes, I'd like them to be re-usable. Thanks.

Comment: i dunno... the only reason i could see that *needing* to be global is if you were to use them in inline events (onclick="somefunction()") which is a bad idea anyway. If you wanted to use them in other scripts, there's better ways of accomplishing that (such as creating a module so that you only have 1 global var rather than 3 and they would be grouped together so that it's clear that they are related)

Comment: It might be an idea to explicitly set them on the window object to make it clear that they should be global (if you're sure that's what you want). p.s. where exactly is the OOP style here? I see functions, but no instantiatable objects. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is a good idea. As your script grows in complexity and gets more dynamic, you'll quickly run into the limitations of a library like jQuery.

Procedural or functional doesn't matter. Modularity matters. Look for a *framework*.

Comment: Thanks Frits, can you suggest any good'uns?

Comment: Google for "js framework" and you'll get some popular ones. Personally I'm using an in-house developed framework so I can't tell you too much about that ;)